# jquery-chosen multiple select only returning one result not an array

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen, multiple-select

```
<select data-placeholder="Select" class="chosen-select" id="test" multiple tabindex="6" name="testing">
<option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
<option value="California">California</option>
</select>
```

When I select both options, it only returns me the last option I clicked if I try any of the following:

```
$('#test').chosen()[0].value;   // note : [1] is null
$('#test').chosen().val();
$('#test').val();
```

Adding the following:
    $('#test').on("change",function(){
       alert($(this).val());
    });
Correct value alerted each time an item is clicked.

Comment: Try this : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/kqd7wfLc/

Comment: `$('#test').val()` works as expected, please see https://jsfiddle.net/kqd7wfLc/3/

Comment: $('#test').on("change",function(){
   alert($(this).val());
});

return's value of the clicked item.

Comment: `$('#test').val()` is the correct way to do this and it does return an array with the multiple selected elements. Can you create a jsfiddle showing the issue? It's possible that some other part of your code is causing the problem

Comment: Thanks Delighted, yeah I am the OP, i just replying to DinoMyte.
Your solution does work.
However means something is interfering with my class along the way I guess. I'll have to strip it back until I find the issue.  Thanks for your jsfiddle

Comment: No worries, yeah I realized after what was going on with the comment. If you can get it to do it in a jsFiddle and cant figure out how to fix it, tag me in a comment with the link and I'll try to help :)

Comment: @DelightedD0D thanks, narrowed it down to msDropdown interferring with it somehow :(

Comment: Hmm, I've never used msDropdown. Do you really need both of them? And are you initializing both of them on the same element?....possibly like `$("select").msDropdown()` , If so, try initializing them with more specific selectors targeting individual elements or something like `$("select:not(#test)").msDropdown()`

Comment: Cheers @DelightedD0D only just seen this, but this is what I did in the end using the not:(#test  and it's fine.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)